# Android to iOS - gradle versus podfile

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am switching from `Android` to `iOS` version of the app that I am making. I am starting to learn iOS. One of the observations I have is that `gradle` equivalent on `iOS` would be `podfile`. However, in Android Studio, I am able to `sync` the `gradle` file from within the Android Studio but for Xcode, I need a separate Terminal window running to install pods using `cocoapods` every time I add, edit or remove a pod. Is there another way with which I can manage everything from within the `Xcode`?

Comment: No this is the only way you have to do. or manually integrate the framework , which you never like.

Comment: Unfortunately, apple has not provided any such mechanism within Xcode. But your concern is absolute correct. There should be inbuild solution within Xcode to handle pod. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaPods is a third-party solution to iOS dependency management that enjoys less first-party support than Gradle does for Android. As such, it is less integrated with the tooling (IDE).

As far as I know, Xcode does not include an integrated Terminal like Android Studio does, so command-line CocoaPods operations will indeed need to be executed outside Xcode.

Depending on your needs, you may find the [CocoaPods Mac app](https://cocoapods.org/app) of interest, though it must also be run outside Xcode.